# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android' in flutter gradle

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.7.11-stable\old_version_2.5\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 763
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\amity-incubator-app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am trying to run a app which was made in 2021 in flutter in older version packages and sdk version. I have upgraded 90+ packages versions but some got discontinued and I tried upgrading the version of gradle property from older to newer.

How to solve to error

Comment: This is hard to diagnose with the amount of information you've provided. I'd recommend that you create a brand new android project and simply copy any relevant code in; this will use packages that are currently working and you can add new ones one at a time to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

1. clean the project
2. go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" check all boxes and then it will restarted
3. update gradle by going gradle and in top right you will see "open for editing in android studio"
4. search for gradle version and update it but be carefull not above 8 beacause it has some issues just stable ok
5. it will automatically download the required gradle and also change in wrapper the gradle version